# How to create files and folders regardless of OS

Tags: java, file-io

I wrote a program and below is a part of it. When I run it on my computer, it works pretty fine. But When I copy this to my friends' PC, it shows `FileNotFoundException` at the forth line.

```
String d = System.getProperty("user.home");
String dir = d + "\\Documents\\CarPark";
new File(dir + "\\abnormal").mkdir();
PrintWriter restoreNo = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(dir + "\\abnormal\\restoreNo.txt"));
```

Any one know where is the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Does your fried also have `\\Documents\\CarPark"` directory structure in its `user.home`? (by default PrintWriter can create files, not directories).

Comment: Did you code it on mac and other's is PC. Consider the way file path are used in different OS.

Comment: Your program probably doesn't have writing permissions. Try run it as admin

Comment: @Pshemo, looks like i found the problm. I try creating the `\\Documents\\CarPark` folder first, thx!

Comment: @Andrew if you want to make the directory programatically look at Danielson answer it should work for you...

Comment: @brso05 yes I'm working on it. tq

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change mkdir to mkdirs. Use File.separator instead of '\', for other OSs

```
String d = System.getProperty("user.home");
String dir = d + File.separator+"Documents"+File.separator+"CarPark";
final File file = new File(dir, "abnormal");
file.mkdirs();// all directories down
PrintWriter restoreNo = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File(file, "restoreNo.txt"));
```

File.separator:

> The system-dependent default name-separator character, represented as
>   a string for convenience. This string contains a single character,
>   namely separatorChar.

mkdir:

> Creates the directory named by this abstract pathname.

mkdirs, from JavaDoc:

> Creates the directory named by this abstract pathname, including any
>   necessary but nonexistent parent directories. Note that if this
>   operation fails it may have succeeded in creating some of the
>   necessary parent directories.

Comment: I'm not quite sure about what is does `mkdirs` do rather than `mkdir`. Hope you can explain a little bit

Comment: So, mkdir creates one directory, first it can't find. mkdirs makes all directories it does not find... Updated answer